# Java scanner to read character frequency from file

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, huffman-code

I'm trying to get a scanner to read the frequency of characters in the filepath, while using a scanner. What should I add to complete this method to do what I've described. Using a priority Queue.

```
public static Huffman build(String filePath) throws IOException {
    if (filePath == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("File doesn't exist");
    } else {
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (file.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(file.nextLine());
            while (s2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.next();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A priority queue is relatively simple, it's a heap that preserves ordering. While a hashmap would probably be better here, pqueue isn't horrific.

Simply go through the entire character array of the file. Put everything in the priority queue. To get the frequency just pop the pqueue and store it in a map or something similar, or output it to wherever you need to output it.

Map is a lot better, but if you have to use a priority queue it's relatively straightforward

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a simple map instead of a priority queue. Using `Files.lines()` and Java Stream you can use this:

```
public static Map<String, Long> build(String filePath) throws IOException {
    if (filePath == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("File doesn't exist");
    }
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        return lines.map(s -> s.split("")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    }
}
```

If you need the order of the characters you can use a `LinkedHashMap`, which stays in insertion order. Change the collector of my above example to this:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting())
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an alternative solution if you don't want to use HasMap or PriorityQueue, You can use a simple frequency array of integer to store the no. of occurrence of all the letters. I have used integer array of size 128 to cover all type of characters including uppercase, lowercase, special character or numbers. (You can add this piece of code right after storing user's input to String s)

```
    int[] count = new int[128]; // initially they all will be zero
    for(char ch:s.toCharArray()){
        count[ch]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<128;i++){
        if(count[i]!=0){
            System.out.println((char)i+":"+count[i]);
        }
    }
```